# Combining only certain cells in two columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have two columns in R, one named Province.State, the other Country.Region. Province.State contains the names of subregions (from states and provinces to overseas territories) within countries (but not all) whereas Country.Region names the country. Here's my dilemma: I need to aggregate my data by country with the overseas territories treated as separate countries for the per capita calulation that I do later. So I want to create a single column listing the country if Province.State lists a province/state within the country or the name of the overseas territory if Provice.State lists the name of the territory.

Sample from my data set:

```
Province.State <- c("Australian Capital Territory", "New South Wales", "Northern Territory", "Queensland", "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria", "Western Australia", "", "", "", "Faroe Islands", "Greenland")

Country.Region <- c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark")

df <- data.frame(Province.State, Country.Region)
```

In this example, I want to aggregate the data for Australia. However, the data for the Faroe Islands and Greenland need to be separate from Denmark proper. I've tried to paste the data `df$country <- paste(df$Province.State, Country.Region, sep = " ")` but that only compounded my issue as I now had to go back and change a number of individual cells.

Edit: I do have a second data set with the names of the countries I want. It looks like this:

```r
Country <- c("Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Denmark", "Faroe Islands", "Greenland")

seconddf <- data.frame(Country)
```

What I would like to do is create a column in df that looks like this:

```r
df$nation <- "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Denmark", "Faroe Islands", "Greenland")
```

Is there a way to do this or am I stuck doing it by hand? Thank you for any help on this vexing problem.

Comment: Lacking immediate memory to geography lessons of years ago, how do we know which country/province pairs you want to keep separate and which you want to combine? For instance, in this case do you want to combine all countries except `"Denmark"`, or are there instances where you will combine one province in a country but not another province in the same country? Is this list of provinces-to-keep-separate known a priori?

Comment: Building on@r2evans, you will need to get a flag that tells you what to combine (or not). This could be coded by hand (least ideal), better look it up somewhere. If worse comes to worse, you could have a look at the worldmap and check for Provinces being "within" the country (that sounds like something {sf} could do). But I would argue there must be a more intuitive way or lookup table. Have you had a look at some of the worldbank data or ISO country codes/associations?

Comment: I do have a list of countries in a second data set I could use as a lookup table.